# Solve these equations simultaneously

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

> Solve these equations simultaneously:
>   $$\eqalign{
>   & {8^y} = {4^{2x + 3}}  \cr 
>   & {\log _2}y = {\log _2}x + 4 \cr} $$

I simplified them first:

$\eqalign{
  & {2^{3y}} = {2^{2\left( {2x + 3} \right)}}  \cr 
  & {\log _2}y = {\log _2}x + {\log _2}{2^4} \cr} $

I then had:

$\eqalign{
  & 3y = 4x + 6  \cr 
  & y = x + 16 \cr} $

Solving:

$\eqalign{
  & 3\left( {x + 16} \right) = 4x + 6  \cr 
  & 3x + 48 = 4x + 6  \cr 
  & x = 42  \cr 
  & y = \left( {42} \right) + 16  \cr 
  & y = 58 \cr} $

---

This is the wrong answer, I would like to understand where I went wrong so I dont make the same mistake again, your help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Note that $\log_2 x + \log_2 (2^4) = \log_2 (16x)$ so your second equation should be $y = 16x$.

Comment: @GitGud I think the OP is trying to combine what's inside the logs. They used the fact that $4 = \log_2 (2^4)$ to get everything in terms of $\log_2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\log _2y = {\log _2}x + \log_22^4$$
$$\log m+\log n=\log (mn)$$
$$\log _2y = \log _2({x\cdot 2^4})$$
$$y=16x$$
this will be second eqn

so equation is

$3y = 4x + 6\;\;$ and $y=16x$

solving these:

$3\times16x = 4x + 6\implies44x=6\implies x=\dfrac3{22
}\;\;,y=\dfrac{24}{11}$

Answer (score 3):

Recall: $\quad\log_2(a) + \log_2(b) = \log_2(ab)$. So

> $$\log_2 x + \log_2 (2^4) = \log_2(x) + \log_2(16) = \log_2 (16x)$$

So your system of equations should be

$$3y = 4x + 6$$
$$ y = 16 x$$

Answer (score 3):

$$
\log_2 y = (\log_2 x) + 4
$$
$$
2^{\log_2 y} = 2^{\log_2 x}\cdot 2^4
$$
$$
y = x\cdot 16
$$
You added where you needed to multiply.

Answer (score 1):

The equation wil be $\log_2 y= \log_2 x + \log_2 2^4$.
so $y$ will then be equal to $16x$.
So $4x$ will be $\dfrac y4$.
Substituting,so $3y=\dfrac y4+6$

$\dfrac {11y}4= 6$

So $y=\dfrac {24}{11}$. And $x=\dfrac {3}{22}$.

Comment: Please use LaTeX